# Azure Data Factory - XML Source type

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a XML file with multiple arrays and using it in a Dataflow, I have requirement to filter out the data based on xml node count 1.Please suggest how can we filter the xml nodes based on the conditions.

Also would like to know is there any feature to use existing xslt file to transform the data in ADF. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well !!!

I think you can use ADF custom activity to filter the nodes.

To transform the XSLT file, you can use Azure Logic Apps [Transform XSLT to CSV using Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/22664/logic-apps-transform-xml-xslt-using-it-to-create-a.html)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dataflow itself has many hierarchy manipulation transforms like flatten transform. You can also use 'map, mapIf, filter' etc. functions to map the structures from one to another. This will avoid you doing custom coding to read/parse/transform XML data within custom activity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions